# How informal are "t'as" and "t'aimes" and similar contractions of tu?

Tags: oral, élision, niveau-de-langue

I very often see transcriptions of French speech abbreviate "tu as" to "t'as" and "tu aimes" to "t'aimes" and similar such contractions.

I understand this is not formally correct but is generally how people talk when speaking quickly.

However, I'm curious, in writing, to what extent is this form casual? I'm hoping someone who's fully fluent in both English and French can make an analogy to something in English.

In writing, when is it appropriate to use *t'as* as opposed to writing it out fully?

I gather it's normal in chat conversations but wrong for a job application. But surely there are many levels in-between...?

Comment: Don't confuse spoken and written French. Non-linguists typically say that some spoken form seen in dialogues etc, as wrong. They aren't. They just are not formal written French.

Answer (score 3):

> In writing, when is it appropriate to use *t'as* as opposed to writing it out fully ?

À l'écrit on peut tout se permettre, mais pas n'importe où ni n'importe quand :
*[T'as d'beaux yeux tu sais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Quai_des_brumes_%28film%29)*
a d'abord été écrit, mais c'est un dialogue de film, et le *de* s'est aussi transformé en *d'*.

Nous sommes dans l'oral, mais dans le domaine intime, de l'amour, où l'on peut difficilement envisager de dire "tu as de beaux yeux", cela reviendrait à dire, avec un accent 'pointu' "Ma chèèère, comme vos yeux sont mââgnifiques", l'emphase n'est pas de mise chez le commun des mortels, elle est réservée à quelques snobs ou aux bourgeois des hautes classes sociales, où le fric, le pouvoir, le paraître sont plus recherchés que l'amour.

Il m'est arrivé de demander "T'aimes ça ?" ou des tournures de cette espèce à mes supérieurs, mais c'était en tête à tête ou en très petit comité, alors que le *vous* est de rigueur dans d'autres circonstances.

À l'écrit, selon l'ambiance, la situation, la proximité ou encore si l'on rapporte des dialogues, on peut utiliser l'apostrophe à bon escient.

L'élision marque donc une proximité des personnes qui se parlent, ne pas la mettre signe une distance, ou une attitude corsetée, contenue... pas naturelle.

Son utilisation est donc une question "d'épiderme", d’à-propos, de circonstances, ou alors elle peut être un test pour sonder les réactions de celui à qui l'on s'adresse.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I may compare this with “wanna” (want to) or “gotta” (got to).

It's faster to speak… But I just say this when I'm with friends, not with my boss…

Writing “t'as” is not correct in French, it's a bad part of what we call “une forme élidée”.

Post scriptum:
I post it as an answer but I hope some specialist could explain better than I do. And it was too long  to post it as a comment. I'm not fluent in English, I've got a technical English…

Comment: That's a really good example! *wanna* is exactly something I would write in a chat but not a job letter.